# regex to validate emails which allows only these two special symbols .,- before @ symbol

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I have used below regex for email validation.

```
var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

How can i validate the below two email id like

1. hello!%#%^world@gmail.com
2. helloworld@-gmail.com

Vaild Email ids:

1. hello-world@gmail.com
2. hello.world@gmail.com

InVaild Email ids:

1. hello!#%#@gmail.com
2. helloworld@-gmail.com

Special characters should not be allow before @gmail.com

Below is my JavaScript code

```
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

if (!re.test($(this).val())) {
    errmsg.push($(this).attr('placeholder') + ' is invalid');
}
```

Comment: I hope you are also doing server-side validation? Remember JS can be disabled. I assume you have already seen this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript).

Comment: post some examples of valid and invalid email id's.

Comment: Myname.mysurnane+something@gmail.com is a valid gmail address

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have updated the question.. let me know if its not clear

Comment: @James I have tried 4-5 regex still can't find the one which matches my requirement .. thanks for writing

Comment: @mplungjan i'm trying to prevent myname.!$%^&mysurname@gmail.com

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/

Comment: @AndyStorrisch you mean this http://regex101.com/r/jZ2eD7/7

Comment: @AndyStorrisch Which special characters do you wish to exclude before the @?  The RFC allows **! \$ & * - = ^ ` | ~ # % ' + / ? _ { }**.  Do you have any other differences from the formal requirements for your validation?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I wanted to exclude all the special character apart for . and - before @

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the below regex to validate emails which allows only these two special symbols  `.`,`-` before `@` symbol.

```
^[^<>()[\]\\,;:\%#^\s@\"$&!@]+@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jZ2eD7/7)